# Properly converting an image for use in blob_log

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image, numpy-ndarray

I'm using scikit-image's `blob_log`, which takes a parameter `image` and counts the blobs in it. The docs say

> [**`image`**](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=blob_log#skimage.feature.blob_log) - 2D or 3D ndarray
>
> Input grayscale image, blobs are assumed to be light on dark background (white on black).

I have a preexisting image, foo.jpg, that I then convert to grayscale using

```
from PIL import Image
image_gray = Image.open("foo.jpg").convert('LA')
```

But I'm getting an error (`AttributeError: ndim`) when I use `image_gray` as an argument in `blob_log`. How do I take the grayscale image and properly turn it into a numpy array? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image_gray = Image.open("foo.jpg").convert('LA')
numpyImage = np.array(image_gray)
```